# Stopping A Count(*) After Condition is met in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

**The Goal:**

I am trying to write a query which gets me the number of pages a user hits during the course of their session.  I want to compare the Min(time) to the Max(time)….however…IF the difference between any two rows is > 20 minutes I want to stop counting the minutes and use that difference as the total. For example:

User 1 - Page 1 – 10:00am

User 1 - Page 2 – 10:10am

User 1 - Page 3 – 10:40am

I’d want the result for User 1 to be 10 minutes. (Since I am grouping on UserID) Had that user kept clicking on pages every 10 minutes for 10 hours. Then I’d want that result just the same. But when there is a 20 minute gap, stop, take the count, and move on.

To clarify - a user CAN have a session longer than 20 minutes. If they click every 15 minutes for an hour - the session I want to capture is 60 minutes. If they click 1 more thing in 15 minutes and then "AFK" for several hours before coming back...i want to capture the number 75 minutes for the session length.

**The Problem:**

However, my companies IIS log does not give me anything other than the time that the page was hit. We decided for lack of better options, we were going to use the difference between the Min and Max time a page was hit to determine the “MinutesForSession”.  The problem is that some users, a lot more than we expected, would log in the AM and then again in the PM…causing the min/max skews to be over 10 hours. When knowing the average user sessions cannot be nearly that long, that data skews off the average we are trying to find.

**My Efforts:**

I have created a temp table called #JulyStats which is a mirror of my production data. I am selecting the UserID, The difference between the min/max time. (time defined as the moment when the User hit the page), and the number of pages they hit. I am excluding out some scripts, fonts, images from the log and due to size wanted to isolate it down to a single day.

```
SELECT #JulyStats.UserID, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, MIN(#JulyStats.time), MAX(#JulyStats.time)) AS MinutesForSession,COUNT(*) AS CountPages
FROM #JulyStats
WHERE #JulyStats.date = '7/28/2014'
AND URL NOT LIKE '%js%'
AND URL NOT LIKE '%css%'
AND URL NOT LIKE '%jpg%'
AND URL NOT LIKE '%gif%'
AND URL NOT LIKE '%ico%'
AND URL NOT LIKE '%png%'
AND URL NOT LIKE '%/KeepAlive%'
AND URL NOT LIKE '%font%'
AND URL NOT LIKE '%axd%'
AND URL NOT LIKE '%htc%'
GROUP BY #JulyStats.UserID
ORDER BY MinutesForSession DESC
```

To try to resolve this myself I attempted to add a Where clause:

```
AND DATEDIFF(MINUTE, MIN(#JulyStats.time), #JulyStats.time) < 20
```

Which resulted in an error referring to an aggregate, and my sql knowledge has me confused on where to properly declare it.

**What I need:**

I am unsure how to get it to stop counting minute totals when the condition of a difference of 20 minutes is met. So either some assistance in writing this query OR perhaps an idea of the keyword/phrase that I need to search the internet by which describes what I am trying to accomplish here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't use any language with a stream query? The program will process in real-time and stop when >20min.  SQL only is compulsory ?

Comment: @Alexis_user I am limited by that which I have to work with here at my organization.

Comment: You can add a id `auto_increment` in your temp. table with the time diff. . Then, finding the min of this id  `where time diff > 20min` and count from 1 to the min of this id. It's just a way...

Comment: Added `sql-server` tag based on the `#` table prefix and the `datediff` usage

Comment: @PatrickHofman - Thank you for the info and clarification. I guess that was indirectly referring to the community who has permissions to moderate.

Comment: @PWilliams0530: how are you determining UserID? Is the SessionID not available on the entry in the IIS log?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating a flag every time there is a gap of 20 minutes or more.  Then count the number of times that flag is true for every row.  Then everything in the same "group" will have the same count.

Let me assume you are using SQL Server 2012+, so you have access to the `lag()` and cumulative sum functionality.  This is a convenience, you can do this with earlier versions of SQL Server.

```
with jst as (
      SELECT js.*,
             (case when datediff(minute,
                                 LAG(time) over (partition by UserId order by time),
                                 time
                                ) < 20
                   then 0 else 1
              end) as StartFlag
      FROM #JulyStats js
      WHERE js.date = '7/28/2014' AND URL NOT LIKE '%js%' AND URL NOT LIKE '%css%' AND
           URL NOT LIKE '%jpg%' AND URL NOT LIKE '%gif%' AND URL NOT LIKE '%ico%' AND
           URL NOT LIKE '%png%' AND URL NOT LIKE '%/KeepAlive%' AND URL NOT LIKE '%font%' AND
           URL NOT LIKE '%axd%' AND URL NOT LIKE '%htc%'
    )
select jst.UserId, jst.grp, min(jst.time), max(jst.time), count(*) as NumSessionPages
from (select jst.*, sum(StartFlag) over (partition by UserId order by time) as grp
      from jst
     ) jst
group by jst.UserId, jst.grp;
```

Comment: I like where this is going, however when attempting to use it - even though i am using SQL Server 2012 (SQL Management Studio 11.0.3128) - It gave me: "'LAG' is not a recognized built-in function name."

Comment: `lag()` is definitely part of SQL Server 2012:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256(v=sql.110).aspx.  Perhaps you are inadvertently using an earlier version or have some compatibility mode set so more recent features aren't available.

Comment: Due to time constraints, I was forced to use excel to come up with the results we needed for our meeting. However, I appreciate the effort and its likely something in the SQL settings where I work that prevented these solutions from working as suggested. So thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

Thanks for clarifying PWilliams0530. Gordon's answer looks good in that case. I have a version here that does not require LAG:

```
--create temp testing table
create table #stats(userid int not null, timestamp datetime2(6))

--get lots of test data 
insert into #stats(userid, timestamp)
select abs(cast(newid() as binary(6)) % 1000) + 1, dateadd(minute, abs(cast(newid() as binary(6)) % 1000) + 1, getdate())
from sys.objects o1, sys.objects o2

--query 
select userid, datediff(minute, min(timestamp), max(timestamp)) session_minutes, count(*) count
from (
    select *, 
        --get the cumulative sum of the flags by user. Note this means each 20 min marker for the user is now unique 
        sum(grp) over(partition by userid order by timestamp) cumul_grp 
    from (
        select userid, timestamp, 
            --if difference between the prev timestamp and this timestamp is >= 20, flag it 
            case 
            when coalesce(datediff(minute, prev_stamp, timestamp), 0) >= 20 then 1
            else 0
            end grp
        from (
            select s.userid, s.timestamp, 
                (
                    select max(s2.timestamp) --get largest time less than the outside query; so this is the next "click" 
                    from #stats s2 
                    where s2.userid = s.userid
                    and s2.timestamp < s.timestamp
                ) prev_stamp
            from #stats s 
        ) x 
    ) y 
) z
--group by the userid and the cumulative flag --- this ensures we only take the 
--time differences with no gaps >= 20 min bc the flag segments the data for us 
group by userid, cumul_grp 
order by 2 desc
```

For Gordon's answer, you likely have a database on SQL Server 2012 this not a compatibility level 110.

If you

```
Alter database set compatibility_level = 110;
```

then it will allow you to use SQL Server 2012's advanced features.

OLD ANSWER:

> Looks like you just want to max out minutes per session at 20. Here's 2 queries that might help you:

```
--keep max minutes for session at 20
SELECT #JulyStats.UserID, 
    case 
    when DATEDIFF(MINUTE, MIN(#JulyStats.time), MAX(#JulyStats.time)) >= 20 then 20
    else DATEDIFF(MINUTE, MIN(#JulyStats.time), MAX(#JulyStats.time)) 
    end AS MinutesForSession,
    COUNT(*) AS CountPages
FROM #JulyStats
WHERE #JulyStats.date = '7/28/2014'
AND URL NOT LIKE '%js%'
AND URL NOT LIKE '%css%'
AND URL NOT LIKE '%jpg%'
AND URL NOT LIKE '%gif%'
AND URL NOT LIKE '%ico%'
AND URL NOT LIKE '%png%'
AND URL NOT LIKE '%/KeepAlive%'
AND URL NOT LIKE '%font%'
AND URL NOT LIKE '%axd%'
AND URL NOT LIKE '%htc%'
GROUP BY #JulyStats.UserID
ORDER BY MinutesForSession DESC

--only return users with 20 or less minutes per session 
SELECT #JulyStats.UserID, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, MIN(#JulyStats.time), MAX(#JulyStats.time)) AS MinutesForSession,
    COUNT(*) AS CountPages
FROM #JulyStats
WHERE #JulyStats.date = '7/28/2014'
AND URL NOT LIKE '%js%'
AND URL NOT LIKE '%css%'
AND URL NOT LIKE '%jpg%'
AND URL NOT LIKE '%gif%'
AND URL NOT LIKE '%ico%'
AND URL NOT LIKE '%png%'
AND URL NOT LIKE '%/KeepAlive%'
AND URL NOT LIKE '%font%'
AND URL NOT LIKE '%axd%'
AND URL NOT LIKE '%htc%'
GROUP BY #JulyStats.UserID
HAVING DATEDIFF(MINUTE, MIN(#JulyStats.time), MAX(#JulyStats.time)) < 20 
ORDER BY MinutesForSession DESC
```

Comment: I appreciate the effort, however a user's session CAN be longer than 20 minutes. If Every 15 minutes for the next hour I click something. The session length will be 60 minutes. If i click 1 more thing and then "AFK" for 2 hours...the session length would be 75 minutes and that is the number I'd seek for the user.

Comment: Due to time constraints, I was forced to use excel to come up with the results we needed for our meeting. However, I appreciate the effort and its likely something in the SQL settings where I work that prevented these solutions from working as suggested. So thank you :)